# Variable assignments affect present running shell

Tags: shell, environment-variables, posix

While writing some code I found out that this line:

```
$ TZ="America/Los_Angeles"       date; echo "$TZ"
Thu Dec 24 14:39:15 PST 2015
```

Correctly gives the actual time at "Los Angeles" and that the value of the variable `TZ` is not retained. All as should be expected.

However, with this line, which I used to get some formats to date expanded, and which essentially executes the same thing, retains the value of TZ:

```
TZ="America/Los_Angeles" eval  date; echo "$TZ"
Thu Dec 24 14:41:34 PST 2015
America/Los_Angeles
```

After several more tests, I found out that this happens only in some shells.
It happens in dash, ksh but not in bash or zsh.

## Q's

The question(s) are:

- Why is the value of TZ being retained in the present shell?
- How could that be avoided/controlled (if possible)?

#### Additional.

I ran tests in several shells with this two lines:

```
myTZ="America/Los_Angeles"
unset TZ; { TZ="$myTZ"      date; } >/dev/null; echo -n "  direct $TZ"
unset TZ; { TZ="$myTZ" eval date; } >/dev/null; echo    "  evaled $TZ"
```

And this results:

```
/bin/ash        :   direct   evaled America/Los_Angeles
/bin/dash       :   direct   evaled America/Los_Angeles
/bin/sh         :   direct   evaled America/Los_Angeles
/bin/bash       :   direct   evaled
/bin/ksh93      :   direct   evaled America/Los_Angeles
/bin/lksh       :   direct   evaled America/Los_Angeles
/bin/mksh       :   direct   evaled America/Los_Angeles
/bin/zsh        :   direct   evaled
/bin/zsh4       :   direct   evaled
```

TZ value affects the running shell in all shells except bash and zsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there is a very specific reason for this behavior.
The description of what happens is a bit longer.

#### Only assignments.

A command line made (only) of assignments will set the variables for *this* shell.

```
$ unset a b c d
$ a=b c=d
$ echo "<$a::$c>"
<b::d>
```

The value of vars assigned will be retained.

#### External command.

Assignments before an external command set variables for *that* shell only:

```
$ unset a b c d
$ a=b c=d bash -c 'echo "one:|$c|"'; echo "two:<$c>"
one:|d|
two:<>
```

And I mean "external" as any command that has to be searched in PATH.

This also apply to normal built-ins (like cd, for example):

```
$ unset a b c d; a=b c=d cd . ; echo "<$a::$c>"
<::>
```

Up to here all is as is usually expected.

#### Special Built-Ins.

But for special built-ins, [POSIX requires that the values are set for this shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14).

> 2. Variable assignments specified with *special built-in utilities* remain in effect after the built-in completes.

```
$ sh -c 'unset a b c d; a=b c=d export f=g ; echo "<$a::$c::$f>"'
<b::d::g>
```

I am using a call to `sh` assuming that `sh` is a POSIX-compliant shell.

This is not something that is usually used.

This means that assignments place in front of any of this list of special built-ins shall retain the assigned values in the present running shell:

```
break : continue . eval exec exit export 
readonly return set shift times trap unset
```

This will happen if a shell works as per POSIX spec.

### Conclusion:

It is possible to set variables for only one command, any command, by making sure the command **is not** a special built-in. The command `command` is a regular builtin. It only tells the shell to use a command, not a function. This line works in all shells (except ksh93):

```
$ unset a b c d; a=b c=d command eval 'f=g'; echo "<$a::$c::$f>"
<::::g>
```

In such case vars a and b are set for the environment of the command command, and discarded after that.

Instead, this will retain assigned values (except bash and zsh):

```
$ unset a b c d; a=b c=d eval 'f=g'; echo "<$a::$c::$f>"
<b::d::g>
```

**Note** that the assignment after eval is single quoted to protect it from unwanted expansions.

So: To place variables in the command environment use `command eval`:

Answer (score 6):

As you've found, that's spec'd behavior. But it also makes sense.

The value is retained in the shell's environment for the same reason the value of other environment variables are retained by other commands when you prefix definitions to their command-lines - you're setting the variables in their environment.

The *special builtins* are generally the most intrinsic variety in any shell - `eval` is essentially an accessible name for the shell's parser, `set` tracks and configures shell options and shell parameters, `return`/`break`/`continue` trigger loop control flow, `trap` handles signals, `exec` opens/closes files. These are all fundamental utilities - and are typically implemented with barely-there wrappers over the meat and potatoes of your shell.

Executing most commands involves some layered environment - a *subshell environment (which needn't necessarily be a separate process)* - which you don't get when calling the special builtins. So when you set environment for one of these commands you set environment for your shell. Because they basically represent your shell.

But they're not the only commands that retain environment that way - functions do the same as well. And errors behave differently for special built-ins - try `cat <doesntexist` and then try `exec <doesntexist` or even just `: <doesntexist` and while the `cat` command will complain, the `exec` or `:` will kill a POSIX shell. The same is true of expansion errors on their command line. They're the *main loop*, basically.

These commands don't *have* to retain environment - some shells wrap their internals up more tightly than others, expose less of the core functionality and add more buffer between the programmer and the interface. These same shells might also tend to be a bit slower than others. Definitely they require a lot of non-standard adjustments to make them to conform to spec. And anyway, it's not as if this is a *bad* thing:

```
fn(){ bad_command || return=$some_value return; }
```

That stuff is *easy*. How else would you preserve the return of `bad_command` so simply without having to set a bunch of *extra* environment and yet still do assignments conditionally?

```
arg=$1 shift; x=$y unset y
```

That kinda stuff works too. In place swaps are more simple.

```
IFS=+  set -- "$IFS" x y z
x="$*" IFS=$1 shift
echo "${x#"$IFS"}" "$*"
```

---

```
+x+y+z x y z
```

...or...

```
expand(){
    PS4="$*" set -x "" "$PS4" 
    { $1; }  2>&1
    PS4=$2   set +x
}   2>/dev/null

x='echo kill my computer; $y'
y='haha! just kidding!' expand "${x##*[\`\(]*}"
```

...is another one I like to use...

```
echo kill my computer; haha! just kidding!
```

Comment: @BinaryZebra - but the point is they dont work differently - when you set variables for some other command they persist in that other executable's environment. when you set variables in your shell's environment they also persist.